# Error al iniciar ubuntu, No init despues de hacer un do-release-upgrade desde 14.04 a 16.04 (kernel panic) + muchas dependencias incumplidas

Tags: ubuntu, dependencias

Tengo un PC MSI de escritorio que contaba con Ubuntu 14.04, y realicé un do-release-upgrade para subir a 16.04. El proceso duró un tiempo, pero terminó con una ventana con error. Pensando que se podría arreglar después de un reinicio.

Lo extraño es que no me dejaba reiniciar ni manualmente (con el mouse arriba a la derecha apagar, no hacía nada) ni por línea de comando al hacer un `sudo reboot` me decía que el comando no existía... Así que decidí hacer un reset apretando el botón de power.

El problema ocurre que al bootear nuevamente, me sale un kernel panic, muy similar a lo que le ocurrió a un usuario que reporto en https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1652462

```
run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory 
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init. 
run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory 
run-init: /etc/init: Permission denied 
run-init: /bin/init: No such file or directory 
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open splash Kernel panic — not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00
```

Siguiendo las mismas instrucciones descritas ahí, me bajé la última versión de ubuntu 16.04, para montarlo en un USB e intentar arreglar desde una versión live de ubuntu.

Las instrucciones fueron las siguiente

1. boot your droplet with a Recovery ISO - Like TigerShark from DigitalOcean
2. Network must be configured, either manually or via TigerShark script.
3. $ mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
4. $ chroot /mnt
5. $ unlink /etc/resolv.conf && echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
6. $ apt-get install init ** desde aca no pude seguir, explico mas abajo**
7. $ update-initramfs -u

Logré acceder al disco, para continuar con el proceso de instalar paquetes, ya que al parecer el upgrade fue inconcluso, y no se instalaron los paquetes correctos o necesario....

Entonces una vez montado, y ejecutado el chroot, intento realizar lo que en todos lados y páinas de ubuntu recomiendan, hacer un **apt-get update** && **apt-get upgrade** && **apt-get -f install**

Pero no se logran completar las instrucciones, y siempre me tira error de dependencias incumplidas, en algunos sitios recomiendan desinstalar los paquetes que tiene conflictos, pero en todos los casos vi que eran pocos paquetes y era fácil el desinstalarlos. No así mi caso, y aunque solo me tira 64 paquetes con errores no logro entender cuál debería eliminar para arreglar el upgrade.

Les comento los errores que me salen al ejecutar los comandos que se recomiendan para solucionar el problema:

**apt-get update ->** no arroja errores

**apt-get upgrade ->** E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apt# sudo apt-get upgrade -f
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 deja-dup : Depends: libgnome-control-center1 (>= 1:3.3.5) but it is not installable
 freerdp-x11 : Depends: libfreerdp1 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
 gnome-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk25 (>= 3.18.0) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libcheese8 (>= 3.18.0) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libcolord-gtk1 (>= 0.1.24) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libgnome-bluetooth13 (>= 3.12.0) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libgoa-1.0-0b (>= 3.16.2) but 3.10.3-0ubuntu1 is installed
                        Depends: libgtop-2.0-10 (>= 2.22.3) but it is not installed
                        Depends: gnome-control-center-data (>= 1:3.18.2-1ubuntu6) but 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 is installed
                        Depends: gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.13.91) but 3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2 is installed
                        Depends: gsettings-desktop-schemas (>= 3.15.4) but 3.10.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
                        Recommends: unity-control-center-faces but it is not installed
                        Recommends: gnome-online-accounts but it is not installed
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.5) but it is not installable
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.5) but it is not installable
 gvfs-fuse : Depends: gvfs (= 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.2) but 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2 is installed
 krename : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.5) but it is not installable
 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libapparmor-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
 libapt-pkg-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libarchive13 : Depends: libnettle4 (>= 2.3) but it is not installable
 libcairo-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libclone-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libcupscgi1 : Depends: libcups2 (= 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.8) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3 is installed
 libcupsimage2 : Depends: libcups2 (= 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.8) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3 is installed
 libcupsmime1 : Depends: libcups2 (= 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.8) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3 is installed
 libcupsppdc1 : Depends: libcups2 (= 1.7.2-0ubuntu1.8) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3 is installed
 libfile-fcntllock-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libfreerdp-core1.1 : Depends: libfreerdp-codec1.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installed
                      Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installed
 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 : Depends: libfreerdp-codec1.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installed
 libfreerdp-plugins-standard : Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installed
 libglib-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libgnutls28 : Depends: libhogweed2 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
               Depends: libnettle4 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
 libgtk2-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
 libhtml-parser-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libio-pty-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libkfilemetadata4 : Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.5) but it is not installable
 liblist-moreutils-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 liblocale-gettext-perl : PreDepends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libnet-dns-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
 libpam-freerdp : Depends: libfreerdp1 (>= 1.0~beta5) but it is not installable
 libpango-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libperl5.18 : Depends: perl-base (= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.3) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2 is installed
 libperlio-gzip-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libpurple0 : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: libetonyek-0.1-1 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libmwaw-0.3-3 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libodfgen-0.1-1 but it is not installed
                    Depends: liborcus-0.10-0v5 (>= 0.9.2-4ubuntu2) but it is not installed
                    Depends: librevenge-0.0-0 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libwps-0.4-4 but it is not installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libclucene-contribs1v5 (>= 2.3.3.4) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libclucene-core1v5 (>= 2.3.3.4) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libcmis-0.5-5v5 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libeot0 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libglew1.13 (>= 1.12.0) but it is not installed
                    Depends: librevenge-0.0-0 but it is not installed
 libreoffice-draw : Depends: libcdr-0.1-1 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libfreehand-0.1-1 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libmspub-0.1-1 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libmwaw-0.3-3 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libodfgen-0.1-1 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libpagemaker-0.0-0 (>= 0.0) but it is not installed
                    Depends: librevenge-0.0-0 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libvisio-0.1-1 but it is not installed
                    Depends: libwpg-0.3-3 but it is not installed
 libreoffice-impress : Depends: libetonyek-0.1-1 but it is not installed
                       Depends: libmwaw-0.3-3 but it is not installed
                       Depends: libodfgen-0.1-1 but it is not installed
                       Depends: librevenge-0.0-0 but it is not installed
                       Recommends: libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer but it is not installed
 libreoffice-ogltrans : Depends: libglew1.13 (>= 1.12.0) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-writer : Depends: libabw-0.1-1v5 but it is not installed
                      Depends: libe-book-0.1-1 but it is not installed
                      Depends: libetonyek-0.1-1 but it is not installed
                      Depends: libmwaw-0.3-3 but it is not installed
                      Depends: libodfgen-0.1-1 but it is not installed
                      Depends: librevenge-0.0-0 but it is not installed
                      Depends: libwpd-0.10-10 but it is not installed
                      Depends: libwpg-0.3-3 but it is not installed
                      Depends: libwps-0.4-4 but it is not installed
 libsocket6-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
 libsub-identify-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libsub-name-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libtext-charwidth-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libtext-iconv-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libtext-soundex-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libuuid-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libwinpr-sspi0.1 : Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installed
 libwinpr-utils0.1 : Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installed
 libxml-libxml-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
 libxml-parser-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 mongodb-clients : Depends: libpcrecpp0v5 (>= 7.7) but it is not installed
 mongodb-server : Depends: libpcrecpp0v5 (>= 7.7) but it is not installed
 php5 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.22) but it is not installable or
                 libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.22) but it is not installable or
                 php5-cgi (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.22) but it is not installable or
                 php5-fpm (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.22) but it is not installable
 remmina-plugin-rdp : Depends: libfreerdp1 (>= 1.0~beta5) but it is not installable
 rhythmbox : Depends: python3 (< 3.5) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
             Depends: rhythmbox-data (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.3-1ubuntu7 is installed
             Depends: gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.3-1ubuntu7 is installed
 rhythmbox-mozilla : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist : Depends: rhythmbox (>= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 vlc-nox : Depends: libebml4 but it is not installable
           Depends: libfreerdp1 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable
           Depends: libmatroska6 but it is not installable
           Depends: libsidplay2 but it is not installable
           Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.7) but it is not installable
           Recommends: libdvdcss2
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

**apt-get -f install ->** E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

(al parecer es muy similar con el anterior) https://pastebin.com/raw/QxmDGFX3

**dpkg --configure -a ->** error tambien, abajo el codigo

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apt# dpkg --configure -a
Setting up ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
mv: '/lib/ufw/user.rules' and '/etc/ufw/user.rules' are the same file
dpkg: error processing package ufw (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up nfs-kernel-server (1:1.2.8-9ubuntu12.1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99teamviewer' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Service rpcbind has to be enabled to start service nfs-kernel-server
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package nfs-kernel-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up cups-daemon (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.3) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99teamviewer' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'teamviewer_start' missing LSB tags and overrides
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'friendly-recovery' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: script virtualbox: service virtualbox already provided!
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'cron' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: There is a loop between service gunicorn and teamviewer_start if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service teamviewer_start at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service gunicorn at depth 1
insserv: Stopping teamviewer_start depends on gunicorn and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package cups-daemon (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-server:
 mongodb-server depends on libpcrecpp0v5 (>= 7.7); however:
  Package libpcrecpp0v5 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99teamviewer' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'teamviewer_start' missing LSB tags and overrides
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'friendly-recovery' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: script virtualbox: service virtualbox already provided!
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'cron' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: There is a loop between service gunicorn and teamviewer_start if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service teamviewer_start at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service gunicorn at depth 1
insserv: Stopping teamviewer_start depends on gunicorn and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package dbus (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up initscripts (2.88dsf-59.3ubuntu2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99teamviewer' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'teamviewer_start' missing LSB tags and overrides
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'friendly-recovery' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: script virtualbox: service virtualbox already provided!
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'cron' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: There is a loop between service gunicorn and teamviewer_start if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service teamviewer_start at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service gunicorn at depth 1
insserv: Stopping teamviewer_start depends on gunicorn and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: warning: script 'S99teamviewer' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'teamviewer_start' missing LSB tags and overrides
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'friendly-recovery' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: script virtualbox: service virtualbox already provided!
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'cron' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: There is a loop between service gunicorn and teamviewer_start if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service teamviewer_start at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service gunicorn at depth 1
insserv: Stopping teamviewer_start depends on gunicorn and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package initscripts (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99teamviewer' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Service mountdevsubfs has to be enabled to start service hwclock
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rpcbind:
 rpcbind depends on initscripts (>= 2.88dsf-13.3); however:
  Package initscripts is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package rpcbind (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of keyboard-configuration:
 keyboard-configuration depends on initscripts; however:
  Package initscripts is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package keyboard-configuration (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ufw
 nfs-kernel-server
 cups-daemon
 mongodb-server
 dbus
 initscripts
 util-linux
 rpcbind
 keyboard-configuration
```

LOGS:

pongo los principales logs que recomiendad revisar

- /etc/apt/source.list -> https://pastebin.com/raw/C9kkibcC
- /var/log/dpkg.log -> lo pegare en pastebin, ya que es muy largo, https://pastebin.com/raw/cXtBuizd
- /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log -> https://pastebin.com/raw/p5HEjvcy

Por favor, si alguien puede guiarme a solucionar este problema, con el live USB-boot podría instalar en una nueva partición, pero la idea no es esa... sé que se puede arregñar, pero estoy medio enredado con los paquetes que debería poder eliminar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como dices el upgrade no se completó correctamente, te recomendaría reiniciarlo pero desde el live cd.

Inicias con el live cd de ubuntu 16.04 y procedes como si fueras a realizar una instalación limpia.

Para no hacer más lento el proceso no selecciones que descargue las actualizaciones, le das a siguiente y eliges la opción que dice "upgrade ubuntu" y le das a instalar; recuerda usar el mismo usuario y la misma contraseña que utilizabas en la versión anterior.

Esperas a que se complete reinicias y todo debería funcionar correctamente.

Saludos.